# FFmpeg drawtext - Could not load fontface from file

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg

I've try to add simple text on top of video with FFmpeg using **drawtext** parameter. Every time i'm going to do this, error is returned:

> Could not load fontface from file 'arial.ttf': cannot open resource

To indicate the location of the font I used the following methods:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Test\rec\vid_1321909320.avi -vf drawtext=fontfile=arial.ttf:text=test -sameq vid_1321909320.flv
ffmpeg -i C:\Test\rec\vid_1321909320.avi -vf drawtext=fontfile=C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf:text=test -sameq vid_1321909320.flv
```

All have failed.  Does anyone have experience with adding text using ffmpeg?

```
FFMPEG version: N-34549-g13b7781 build on Nov 6 2011
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot have a colon in the path to your font file as the colon acts as a key sepperator in ffmpeg. [I had the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182725/how-to-add-text-to-a-video-with-ffmpeg-and-python/8212955#8212955).

#### try:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Test\rec\vid_1321909320.avi -vf drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text=test -sameq vid_1321909320.flv
```

Answer (score 19):

A colon ":" and a backslash "\" have special meaning when specifying the parameters for drawtext. So what you can do is to escape them by converting ":" to "\:" and "\" to "\\".
Also you can enclose the path to your font file in single quotes incase the path contains spaces.

So you will have

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Test\rec\vid_1321909320.avi -vf drawtext=fontfile='C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf':text=test vid_1321909320.flv
```

Comment: Answer from 2011 was not working but adentum's answer worked.

Comment: Still usefull in 2015.

Comment: Still usefull in 2017

Comment: :D So I am an archaeologist :)

Comment: Still useful in 2018!

Comment: @adentum: The age of your reply (6 years) is now greater than the age of the question at the time your reply (1 year). What do you call a fossilised archaeologist?

Comment: Did not work with me, this did:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47432274/920323

Comment: Using forward slashes is the appropriate way to reference a font file, even on Windows. To do this properly, I escaped the colon and use forward slashes, and enclosed it in single quotes, e.g. `fontfile='C\:/WINDOWS/fonts/lucon.ttf'`

Comment: Windows 10 fix: Copy font from C:\Windows\Fonts\Lato\Lato-Bold.ttf to the same folder as where the input file is located. Then just reference it like so ```drawtext=fontfile=Lato-Bold.ttf```

Answer (score 5):

I was also having trouble with ffmpeg recognizing Windows paths.  I finally just put the font Arial.ttf in the same folder as the input file and it worked.

```
[drawtext @ 03C66EA0] Key '/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf: text' not found.
[drawtext @ 03C66E00] Error parsing options string: 'fontfile=C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf: text=Test Text:x=100: y=50: fontsize=24: fontcolor=yellow@0.2: box=1: boxcolor=red@0.2'
Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf: text=Test Text:x=100: y=50: fontsize=24: fontcolor=yellow@0.2: box=1: boxcolor=red@0.2'
Error opening filters!
```

Comment: Using forward slashes is the appropriate way to reference a font file, including on Windows. To do this on my Win10 machine, I escaped the colon, used forward slashes and enclosed the path in single quotes, e.g. `fontfile='C\:/WINDOWS/fonts/lucon.ttf'`