# ffmpeg: drawtest cannot find font for the family Sans

Tags: video, fonts, ffmpeg

I have an avi video and I want to display frame number in the video.

Frame rate = 40fps

I'm using this script:

```
ffmpeg -i maxSSIM_realTime_C_L_560x448.avi -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text=%{n}: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099"   -qscale 0 -y maxSSIM_real_time.avi
```

But I get `[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0000000000732d00] Cannot find a valid font for the family Sans`.

Where can I find fonts in windows 7?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FFmpeg drawtext - Could not load fontface from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103808/ffmpeg-drawtext-could-not-load-fontface-from-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the full path to the font file:  `fontfile='C\:\\Windows\\fonts\\Arial.ttf'`

Answer (score 4):

The fonts on android device are stored at "/system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf". So the command looks like this. This is working for me on android device.

val subtitlecommand = arrayOf(
"-y",
"-i",
videoPath,
"-vf",
"drawtext=fontfile=/system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf:text='Super User':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white",
"-c:a",
"copy",
appDir
)